# Formatting Windows on a dual booted computer

Tags: windows-10, dualboot

I am running win10 and manjaro on the same hdd.
I am having issues with win10 and i want to reset it.
I will reset it  using this method:
Setting-> reset PC
But i don't want to erase manjaro i want to keep it.
Will this affect my manjaro distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to replace Windows 10 in place without affecting other partitions around it, the best way is with Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

Use the option to Keep Nothing: this deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.

This will do what you want and will not affect any other partitions.

Comment: Deal thank you very much ! @John

Comment: You should mark my answer then if you will.